# Unset Additional info in Magento

Tags: layout, magento

I am wondering how to unset product additional info in layout.xml.I created local.xml and used `<action method="unsetChild"><name></name>product_additional_data</name>`.
But it is not working.Any suggestions?

Comment: read your question through again and try to answer it yourself. Try to address at least what exactly, where exactly, how exactly you added and expect things to change. By "exactly" I mean layout references that you need to unset and show the code how you tried to achieve that. You can imagine that no one else has the same setup as you have currently on your site and few are bothering to imagine it. Start from http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML snippet is badly formed. It looks like you were attempting:

```
<action method="unsetChild"><name>product_additional_data</name></action>
```

You might also try this:

```
<remove name="product_additional_data" />
```